# Stopping a scrollTop animation if user touches screen

Tags: jquery

I have a script that scrolls down a long page to a specific div on that page. How would I allow the user wants to stop the page from scrolling to the specified div during the scrolling animation?

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top - 50
}, 1500);
```

I want to stop the animation before 1500 seconds is over using a click action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "**touches screen**" you mean on a mobile browser? Mobile browsers have some delayed response when it comes to `click()` event, so to get this done smoothly you should catch the mobile platforms `touchstart` or `touchend` events:

```
$("html, body").on('touchend click', function(){ 
    $("html, body").stop(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code

```
stop is the id of the button

      $( "#stop" ).click(function() {
        $( "html, body" ).stop();
      });
```

Comment: what if i just want to allow the user to click anywhere on the screen?

Comment: $( "html, body" ).click(function() {
        $( "html, body" ).stop();
      });